# Rails 7 Routing

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-7

I can't figure this out. On a fresh new app there is always a http request GET "/cart.json"

here is the server log

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2023-02-10 16:06:40 -0500
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering home/index.html within layouts/application
  Rendered home/index.html within layouts/application (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 228)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 151.0ms | Allocations: 50896)
Completed 200 OK in 158ms (Views: 154.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 53881)


Started GET "/cart.json" for ::1 at 2023-02-10 16:06:42 -0500
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/cart.json"):
```

Pages render fine but sometimes it interrupts controller logic and data handling in more complex applications

My routes file is bare as well

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  root "home#index"
end
```

Comment: `/cart.json` is not coming from your route configuration. Somewhere in the app it is making a call to <your_url>/cart.json . Your console output just shows that someone is calling this `/cart.json` route on your app. You can quickly find it by searching for all text in all files. If you are on Linux, you can use `silversearcher` and syntax for that is `ag "cart.json" .` If `/cart.json` is something you expect, then you have to define that route first.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not expecting /cart.json and it’s not in my app

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Some extension on chrome kept calling cart.json. If I goto the page using an incognito window cart.json is no longer called